# How to get or calculate lat and long inside a rectangle drawn on Google Maps?

Tags: algorithm, google-maps-api-3

I have a zip codes table which has lat and long columns. I draw a rectangle shape on Google Maps. I want to know how to query the table while having top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right coordinates (so I can find all the rows contained within that shape's bounds).

Thank you!

Comment: what problem are you facing? have you tried `bottom_latitude < your_latitude < top_latitude` and the same for longitude using left and right, for the whole column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know your map bounds (as you said), then you can figure out a min/max latitude and longitude.

Assuming you are using MySQL or alike you could query your DB like:

`SELECT * from YOUR_TABLE where (lat > min_lat and lat < max_lat and lng > min_lng and lng < max_lng)`

This is simplified syntax. Adapt it to the language you are using.